# Fast scheme for the evaluation $x^k$ for $k\in[0,1]$

Tags: numerical-methods

In numerical analysis, we have the [scheme](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Methods_of_computing_square_roots#Babylonian_method) to evaluate $x^{1/2}$ or more generally the [scheme](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nth_root_algorithm) to evaluate $x^{1/n}$.

For $x^k$ with $k\in[0,1]$, is there a fast scheme to evaluate it? My naive implement is writting $k$ into fration like $k=\frac{\alpha}{\beta}$, but it seems that this method will not work for irrational number and the computation is expensive. I am wondering in programming
like mathematica or matlab, how is $x^k$ calculated?

Comment: Not sure we'd use rhe word "scheme" in English. "Algorithm" might be used, or, less formally, "method."

Comment: There's no such thing as "irrational numbers" in finite-precision arithmetic... ;) so, find the continued fraction approximant that is nearest to $k$ and proceed as in the rational case...

Comment: The quick and dirty approach would be to take a sufficiently close rational number, as J.M. said.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do $x^\alpha = \exp(\alpha \ln x)$, use a [CORDIC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CORDIC) algorithm for the functions.